# Hello I have problem with my request to db (React-mongo)

Tags: mongodb, react-redux, cpanel

I followed a nice tutorial on udemy, MERN app, and when it's hosted on Heroku I have no problem

When I host it on my VPS i can naviguate throw my different pages but i don't have response from database ,
instead they say :

```
 "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."
```

and the response is my

```
index.html
```

**I had to configure htaccess like this to actually see the app:**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

**In my server.js i did like this:**

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'))
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'))
})
```

**Proxy :**

```
"proxy": "http://exemple.com:5000",
```

Please let me know what else to try to debug this issue,i can give any other code lines if needed .

Hope someone can deliver me from this stuggle !

Thx
Julien

Comment: Look in the network tab and see what files won't load. Make sure you started the server correctly and make sure all files are on the server.

Comment: Hello its probably because i didn't run mongodb ,is it automaticly made on heroku  build? Thx

Comment: @HMR hey ,how to start correctly the server? what i described as answer come from network tab